# convert parameter from multiselect checkbox of jsp page

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, httprequest

```
<input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="HBO">HBO <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="FOXP">FOX Película <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="FOX">FOX + <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="cotizar" name="Cotizar" />
<br><br>
```

I'm trying to bring from an index.jsp the premium parameter of a checkbox, in a servlet of a client of a web service. I have to save it as a list but what I have tried has not worked

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String plan = request.getParameter("plan");
    String  PREMIUM = request.getParameter("premium");
```

How do I convert request.getParameter ("premium") into a list?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] premiums = request.getParameterValues("premium");
```

Comment: show the error : incompatibles types: String cannot be converted to String []

Comment: You must done something wrong. Note that the function being used is `getParameterValues`

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the checkbox inside of `form` then only multiple values will be sent to server.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="HBO">HBO <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="FOXP">FOX Película <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="premium" value="FOX">FOX + <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="cotizar" name="Cotizar" />
</form>
```

**Servlet:**

To get multiple values we need to use `getParameterValues()`, if you any value for the given parameter name it will give string array of values. If we have one value it will given string array with length of 1.

```
 String[] premiums = request.getParameterValues("premium");
```

If no value sent to server then above method will return `null` value.